# Interpolation of jacobians for point wise defined transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, interpolation, image-processing

Here is my question: let's say that I have a transformation function T from the image A to the image B which is pointwise defined. That is, T(**x**) = J, where J is the jacobian representing the transformation.

What if I want to know the transformation at a point which does not belong to the grid, i.e. between pixels? Can I somehow interpolate between the neighboring jacobian matrices? How?

My initial idea was to break down each jacobian in the constituting components (rotation, translation and scaling) and interpolate between them. But I'm not so sure how meaningful this can be.